# AWS X-Ray Sampling Graph not showing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have a lambda function written in c# which is also accessible through API Gateway. I have enabled X-Ray tracing for both of them i.e. Lambda and API gateway. To view better traces I have created a sampling rule in AWS Console, As mentioned below image but I am not able to get any data in the graph for that sampling rule.
[image]
I have also tried to add sampling rules from code, as in the image below
[image]
The JSON file is something like this
[image]

I will really appreciate it if you can guide me to get trace data in the sampling rule graph.

A question that I have in mind, If I create a new sampling rule, do I have to make changes to the code as well? If yes, what will be the required changes for lambda (C#) code.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda will adopt the default sampling rule, which is 1 request per second and 5 percent of additional requests and the sampling rule in Lambda can't be configured at this moment. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html